# What is the smallest subnet one can create on AWS in the VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-vpc

I want to limit the number of instances that can run in a subnet to the smallest number of instances possible. This in combination with an IAM role will allow me to limit how many instances a user can create on my AWS account (see https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=174503 requirement #4 which reflects my motivations).

What is the smallest subnet one can create on AWS in the VPC and what would the IPv4 CIDR be?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

16 IPs is the smallest range for a VPC Subnet -- `/28` netmask.

For example, you could create a VPC with the CIDR range `10.0.0.0/26` which would support up to 64 IPs in the range of `10.0.0.0` - `10.0.0.63`.

Then you could create 4 subnets, each with 16 available IPs using the following VPC CIDR ranges:

```
10.0.0.0/28   (10.0.0.0  - 10.0.0.15)
10.0.0.16/28  (10.0.0.16 - 10.0.0.31)
10.0.0.32/28  (10.0.0.32 - 10.0.0.47)
10.0.0.48/28  (10.0.0.48 - 10.0.0.63)
```

**NOTE:** See important comment below by @sqlbot. Not all 16 in range can be used for instances.

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed to know.

Comment: Of the 16, there would only be 11 available for use by instances, ELBs (minimum 2 per balancer), and NAT Gateways.  The all-0, all-1 are unassignable, +1 is the default gateway, and +2 and +3 are [reserved by the VPC infrastucture](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Subnets.html#VPC_Sizing).

Comment: if you had a netmask of /29 you would have 8 addresses. Minus the 5 that the VPC requires.  That would leave you with three.  So why is this not the answer?

Comment: @KingAndrew: see https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/ -- `/28` is just the minimum range that AWS will allow you to create.

Comment: @DaveMaple  I didn't doubt your answer but I was thinking that there should be a reason for /28 and not /29.  cheers

Comment: per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing, for /28, it is 16, for /29, it is 8. There are /30, /31, /32 that allow 4,2, 1 host respectively. As AWS has reserved 5 IPs, meaning those are excluded. but /29 should be ok out of my head.

Comment: I think with /29 you might not be able to create a subnet, as that will again mean reserving a few IP addresses, and that is why even with /28 you can create only one subnet.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html#:~:text=The%20first%20four%20IP%20addresses%20and%20the%20last%20IP%20address%20in%20each%20subnet%20CIDR%20block%20are%20not%20available%20for%20you%20to%20use%2C%20and%20cannot%20be%20assigned%20to%20an%20instance.%20For%20example%2C%20in%20a%20subnet%20with%20CIDR%20block%2010.0.0.0/24%2C%20the%20following%20five%20IP%20addresses%20are%20reserved%3A

Answer (score 0):

20191214: AWS provides /29 CIDR and allow /31 per https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/faqs/

quoted below:

> Q: In the case of public virtual interface, I will need /29 public
>   IPv4 addresses. Will AWS provide me with /29 public IPv4 Classless
>   Inter-Domain Routing (CIDR)?
>
> Yes, upon request, AWS will provide you with /29 public IPv4 CIDR
>   block addresses.
>
> Q: Do I have to use /29 or can I use two /31 for my logical redundancy
>   sessions?
>
> For simplified routing, it's recommended to use the default /29
>   addresses for a single virtual interface. If there is a requirement
>   for your network to have multiple /31 addresses you can create two
>   separate /31 addresses for a single VIF. BGP peering on these two /31
>   addresses will terminate on multiple AWS devices for high
>   availability.

The smallest allowed CIDR block in AWS is /31

However, as the original question is about VPC Subnet, which is a different story, as AWS have some reserved IP for each subnet.

Per AWS VPC faq doc here: https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/

> Q. Is there a limit on how large or small a subnet can be?
>
> The minimum size of a subnet is a /28 (or 14 IP addresses.) for IPv4.
>   Subnets cannot be larger than the VPC in which they are created.
>
> For IPv6, the subnet size is fixed to be a /64. Only one IPv6 CIDR
>   block can be allocated to a subnet.
>
> Q. Can I use all the IP addresses that I assign to a subnet?
>
> No. Amazon reserves the first four (4) IP addresses and the last one
>   (1) IP address of every subnet for IP networking purposes.

So, the answer is /28 for IPv4.

Comment: The first part of the answer is not related to the question, it's about direct connect public VIFs public IP addresses.