# AWS IAM user - Limit number EC2 instances and limiting EBS storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am trying to see if its possible to restrict(set some max limit) the number of EC2 instances which are created by an IAM user? Can i create custom policy for this?

**Note:** I am looking for IAM user level permission. Not AWS Account level restriction.

Similarly i am also looking for restricting EBS storage limit per IAM user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One general solution to this kind of requirement is reactive, not proactive. Write automation based on CloudTrail Logs or AWS Config or by simply enumerating the current state of your AWS account periodically, and raise alerts (or terminate resources) if your policies have not been complied with.

Comment: Thank you for the guiding me in right direction. I am working on it as we speak. I will update further once its completed.

Comment: I am able to implement it successfully based on your suggestion. Basing my deletion on Instance-ID. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot limit the number of EC2 instances by IAM.

> Today, you can't limit the number of instances using an IAM policy, though I believe you can limit the overall number of instances per AWS account.

It does look like you can limit EBS sizes, but I don't believe you can limit the total account storage size through IAM.  This reference covers individual EBS size: [How to limit EC2 EBS volume size for ec2:RunInstances in IAM policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49104681/how-to-limit-ec2-ebs-volume-size-for-ec2runinstances-in-iam-policy)

**References:**

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=174503

[How to limit EC2 EBS volume size for ec2:RunInstances in IAM policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49104681/how-to-limit-ec2-ebs-volume-size-for-ec2runinstances-in-iam-policy)

Comment: Thank you for providing details. I am able to restrict the EBS based on your suggestion. EC2 is though a lil bit complicated. working on it based on @jarmod suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could limit it to some degree by defining a very small subnet and only letting the IAM role launch into that specific subnet. See the accepted answer at [What is the smallest subnet one can create on AWS in the VPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41947212/what-is-the-smallest-subnet-one-can-create-on-aws-in-the-vpc) for details on this approach.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I do understand your point. I read the thread which you mentioned. However we have large number of IAM users creating many EC2 instances simultaneously. Number of IP addresses will not be enough for my requirement. It will be very helpful if we are creating limited number of EC2 instances. Otherwise we have to provision large number of subnets every time we need more instances and more configuration is needed. So i think even though your approach is correct it will not be feasible for my requirement. let me know if my approach here is correct.

Comment: Hi Paven, given the large number of IAM users you mention, I think jarmod's recommended approach will best suit your needs.

Comment: Sure.. Working on it.. Thank you :)