# AWS Invalid Subnet Range - Terraform, why are these two subnets invalid?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc

This is my VPC and Subnet Ranges. The two public subnets are not creating, i'm getting the following error message when doing a Terraform Apply.

Error: creating EC2 Subnet: InvalidSubnet.Range: The CIDR '10.0.4.232/29' is invalid.
Error: creating EC2 Subnet: InvalidSubnet.Range: The CIDR '10.0.4.224/29' is invalid.

```
cidr                    = "10.0.4.0/24"
public-subnet-cidr-1    = "10.0.4.224/29"
public-subnet-cidr-2    = "10.0.4.232/29"
private-subnet-cidr-1   = "10.0.4.0/27"
private-subnet-cidr-2   = "10.0.4.32/27"
```

Am I going mad? I'm sure these ranges are correct.

Tried to deploy a VPC and 4 subnets with terraform but the two public subnets are not deploying as it states the IP Cidr range is invalid. Although, to my calculations, it is not invalid.

Comment: The error message is not great. 10.0.4.224/29 is a valid CIDR and a valid subnet of 10.0.4.0/24, it's just that /29 (or smaller) is [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41947212/what-is-the-smallest-subnet-one-can-create-on-aws-in-the-vpc) by AWS VPC.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [AWS VPC documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-ip-addressing.html), the smallest subnet range allowed is `/28` which would give a subnet 16 total IP addresses. A `/29` would give a subnet only 8 total IP addresses, and subnets that small are simply not supported by AWS.

Please note that in every AWS VPC subnet there are 5 [reserved IP addresses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/subnet-sizing.html), so a `/29` subnet would only have 3 usable IP addresses.

Comment: If I change to this, I still get an error message.

I don't see how this is invalid?

"Error: "10.0.4.232/28" is not a valid IPv4 CIDR block; did you mean "10.0.4.224/28"?"

cidr                    = "10.0.4.0/24"
public-subnet-cidr-1    = "10.0.4.224/28"
public-subnet-cidr-2    = "10.0.4.232/28"
private-subnet-cidr-1   = "10.0.4.0/27"
private-subnet-cidr-2   = "10.0.4.32/27"

Comment: Plug the values for that invalid subnet into here: https://mxtoolbox.com/SubnetCalculator.aspx and you will see it is not the IP range you might think it is. It also overlaps with the other public subnet's IP range. You need to look at the IP range of your subnets, and start the next subnet at the next available IP.